# GCC produces code with Unaligned Address Error on m68k when defining a local string

Tags: c, gcc, 68000

I am declaring a string that is 5 bytes long (including the null terminator) in a function:

```
int main(){ 
    char fstring[] = "AAAA";
    ...
```

Which generates the following asm code:

```
main:
link.w %fp,#-16
move.l #1094795585,-13(%fp)
clr.b -9(%fp)
...
```

`move.l` or `move.w` to an odd address causes an Address Error
exception on 68k.
Is there anyway to force the compiler to emit correct code?

Comment: Try `-mstrict-align`? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/M680x0-Options.html#M680x0-Options

Comment: If the compiler emits incorrect code for valid C code, you should report it as a bug.

Comment: I don't know a lot about m68k, but is unaligned access *always* an error on all m68k processors across the board?  Or does it vary depending on specific submodel / device / configuration?  If the latter, it is reasonable for the compiler to support both ways, and so then it's a question of why the default is not correct for your particular system.

Comment: `-mstrict-align` Did not help unfortunately.  I'm not sure about later models, but the flag is set to `-m68000`. I am using the `m68k-linux-gnu-gcc` compiler which can be installed with `apt install gcc-m68k-linux-gnu`.

Comment: What's the full command line you're using to compile this program. Are you using any of the options that affect alignment?

Comment: Just `m68k-linux-gnu-gcc -Iinclude -m68000 main.c -o bin/_main.o -c`

Comment: @user1812 Hmm, that should be fine. What version of the distribution are you running? On Ubuntu, I notice that the older versions of the OS use quite out-of-date GCC versions for m68k.

Comment: Looks like 22.04. I found something interesting. I compiled the `m68k-elf-gcc` compiler from https://github.com/kentosama/m68k-elf-gcc and it produces the correct code. Looks like it has different flags during compilation, and also uses a older GCC version. Here is a pastbin of the -v output for these two compilers: https://pastebin.com/bwstBvW7  . Where Can I report the bug in `m68k-linux-gnu-gcc`?

Comment: GCC bugs can be reported here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/

Comment: If it's only reproducible with your distribution's gcc package, and not with stock gcc built from official GNU source, then you should report it to your distribution maintainer instead of to gcc.gnu.org.  This looks like a Debian-based distribution, so try `reportbug m68k-linux-gnu-gcc`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're compiling for the original 68000, this is definitely a bug. Writing a word or longword to an odd memory address is always an alignment fault and the compiler should be smart enough to know this.